# Check Value of bool in Rust Macro

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros

I'd like to create a macro that checks the value of a provided bool and returns a string based on that value. I tried this:

```rust
macro_rules! dbg_bool{
    () => {};
    ($val:expr $(,)?) => {
        match $val {
            //if $val is true return a green string
            $($val == true) => {
                "it was true".green()
            }
            //if $val is false return a red string
            $($val == false) =>{
                "it was false".red()
            }
        }
    };
    ($($val:expr),+ $(,)?) => {
        ($(dbg_bool!($val)),+,)
    };

}
```

but this gives me the error:

```
error: expected one of: `*`, `+`, or `?`
  --> src/macros.rs:28:32
   |
28 |               $($val == true) => {
   |  ________________________________^
29 | |                 "it was true".green()
30 | |             }
   | |_____________^
```

What's the proper way to use equality operators to compare the `$var` in my macro?

Comment: The `$()` around the match arms is redundant, but also why are you matching `$val` then doing an additional `$val == true` and `$val == false` check?

Comment: is a macro necessary? can't this be done with a normal function?

Comment: @kmdreko it could be but I like to use macros for all my debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `match` syntax doesn't change in a macro:

```
macro_rules! dbg_bool{
    () => {};
    ($val:expr $(,)?) => {
        match $val {
            //if $val is true return a green string
            true => {
                "it was true".green()
            }
            //if $val is false return a red string
            false => {
                "it was false".red()
            }
        }
    };
    ($($val:expr),+ $(,)?) => {
        ($(dbg_bool!($val)),+,)
    };
}
```

As an aside, you are assuming the trait that gives you `green` and `blue` are in scope when you use the macro. For robustness, you'll want to either call it explicitly like `::colored::Colorize::green("it was true")` or wrap the `match` in a block so you can add a `use ::colored::Colorize;` (assuming you're using the [colored](https://crates.io/crates/colored) crate). See these two options on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=814a00859d9fc47d987a144aef96f8b5).

Answer (score 0):

You just match on `$val`, there is no special syntax.

```rust
macro_rules! dbg_bool{
    () => {};
    ($val:expr $(,)?) => {
        match $val {
            true => {
                "it was true"
            }
            false =>{
                "it was false"
            }
        }
    };
    ($($val:expr),+ $(,)?) => {
        ($(dbg_bool!($val)),+,)
    };
}
```